# Bing translator exception from en-us to 'fr-ca'

Tags: c#

i've started using Bing API translator. all the things is ok but when I tried to translate to it with culture code 'fr-ca',fr-FR then it is translating only using language code 'fr' not with culture code (ca, FR) 'fr-ca', 'fr-FR'.

When I called this API method to translate

```
translationQuery.Execute().ToList();
```

throws this exception :

```
--------An error occurred while processing this request.
```

and the inner exception is :

```
--------"Parameter: To has an invalid pattern of characters"

source :  System.Data.Services.Client
```

can any one help me about this problem? and tell me how to translate text with culture code with anyway either API or something else ?

Thanks In advance

sunil

Thanks for your response.

I have more than 10 files and each files have 1000 words that needs to transalate into another languages on bases of culture code not only language code.

English      en-GB British English
             en-US American English
             en-CA Canadian English

Spanish      es-ES Castilian Spanish (as written and spoken in Spain)
             es-MX Mexican Spanish
             es-AR Argentine Spanish
             es-CO Colombian Spanish

Portuguese  pt-PT European Portuguese (as written and spoken in Portugal)
            pt-BR Brazilian Portuguese

Chinese    zh-CN   Mainland China, simplified characters
           zh-TW   Taiwan, traditional characters
           zh-HK   Hong Kong, traditional characters

Instead of doing translation manually is there any others way to translate e.g(es-ES,es-MX,es-CO, es-AR ) ?. since its langauge code is same for all eg:-(es) but have different culture code for each languages. So it may be case that some words have different meaning in es-es and have diffent means in es-MX, es-Co etc.

it would be helpful if found a way to translate on bases of culture code?

Thanks in Advance

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Bing translator doesn't support Canadian French, only Standard French:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456380.aspx

> Microsoft Translator continually adds to the list of supported languages for the Translation and Text to Speech methods. You can always obtain the current list of available language codes using the
>   GetLanguagesForTranslate() or GetLanguagesForSpeak() methods. These methods will return a language code. You can translate that language code into a friendly name in any of the supported languages using the GetLanguageNames() method. Below are the friendly names in English - you can retrieve them in any of the listed languages using GetLanguageNames(). Here is the list (as of February 2014):
>
> ...
>
> fr French

If you want to use Canadian French, you'll have to perform the relevant word swaps afterwards manually.

Ss an aside, Google Translate also only supports Standard French.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Please see the modified question after got your response.